# Optimizing a large number of INSERT ... SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, insert

I have a MySQL InnoDB database with two tables related by a foreign key. Each time a row is inserted into one it uses an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement from the other to get the corresponding foreign key.

I have an application that is continuously doing a large number of these `INSERT ... SELECT` statements to populate this database. I have read that using a multiple row insert, i.e. `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), ...`, can be significantly faster than individual inserts. Unfortunately it appears that splitting the database into separate tables prevents me from taking advantage of this? Is there a workaround or another way to improve the speed of these inserts?

EDIT:

Would any of the following be likely to help?

1. Combining the `INSERT ... SELECT` statements with a `UNION`.
2. A multiple row insert into a temporary table followed by a `JOIN` and
   a single `INSERT ... SELECT`.
3. Splitting the inserts among multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

## SUGGESTIONS

- Increase the size of your Log Buffer. The default value for [**innodb_log_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size) is 8M. You should make 256M or 512M. (Restart Required)
- Turn off the Double Write Buffer. Set [**innodb_doublewrite**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_doublewrite) to 0. (Restart Required)
- OPTIONAL : Temporarily [disable change buffering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_change_buffering), which throttles secondary index updates.
- OPTIONAL : In your application, you should limit the number of rows to insert. Try insert 500 or 1000 rows at a time. If the rows have long VARCHAR columns, then insert 100 or 200 rows at a time.

## SUMMARY

Add these lines to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_doublewrite = 0
```

then, restart mysql.

If these do not improve things, then try disabling the change buffering with

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_change_buffering = 'none';
```

You could always change it back to 'all' after a number of large bulk inserts.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will experiment with these. Do you know if there is any way I can better restructure the queries themselves?